# Visual Studio Db project with custom static code analyzer

Tags: visual-studio, static-code-analysis, sqlproj

I've troubles with adding some sample code analyzer into a db project.
I followed this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632175(v=vs.103).aspx
, but custom analyzer hadn't added. 
What I was missing? 

P.S. I'm using `VS 2015 Enterprise` with `SSDT 2016`

Comment: What new tests are you adding? Anything useful worth sharing with the SQL community?

Comment: I was trying to add rule, that will check, if any unnamed constraint is exist.

Comment: As a workaround, I created msbuild task, that triggers After build of the project.

Comment: But did you manage to add the rule using the SSDT static analysis framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are certain all is good from your side, it's probably due to the dll being in the wrong folder.  When I hit this issue I find it easiest to run with logging and place the dll where ssdt is looking to rather than trial and error placing in random folders ☺

Kevin Cunnane has described the procedure in the comments on this page

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/06/30/sql-server-data-tools-july-update-2/